# Unable to retrieve count from Cosmos Stored Procedure

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am unable to retrieve count of document based on provided filter query to procedure. Here are the details -

SP Script

```
function count(filterQuery, continuationToken) {
var collection = getContext().getCollection();
var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
var maxResult = 25;
// The number of documents counted.
var result = 0;

tryQuery(continuationToken);

// Helper method to check for max result and call query.
function tryQuery(nextContinuationToken) {
    var responseOptions = { continuation: nextContinuationToken, pageSize: maxResult };
    if (result >= maxResult || !query(responseOptions)) {
        setBody(nextContinuationToken);
    }
}

function query(responseOptions) {
    var query = "SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c WHERE c.ActivityId='1816820'";
    return (query && query.length) ?
        collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query, responseOptions, onReadDocuments) :
        collection.readDocuments(collectionLink, responseOptions, onReadDocuments);
}

function onReadDocuments(err, queryFeed, responseOptions) {
    if (err) {
        console.length(err);
        throw 'Error while reading document: ' + err;
    }

    console.log(queryFeed);     //prints 0
    result += queryFeed[0];

    if (responseOptions.continuation) {
        tryQuery(responseOptions.continuation);
    } else {
        setBody(null);
    }
}

function setBody(continuationToken) {
    var body = { count: result, continuationToken: continuationToken };
    getContext().getResponse().setBody(body);
}
```

}

Here is the screenshot. Just to be sure, I have written query hard-coded here for the time being. Otherwise I was passing thru parameter.

[image]

Here is direct query result -

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Is your partition key path `/ActivityId`?

Comment: Yes, @SteveZhao. It is "/ActivityId"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For partitioned containers, when executing a stored procedure, a
> partition key value must be provided in the request options. Stored
> procedures are always scoped to a partition key. Items that have a
> different partition key value will not be visible to the stored
> procedure.

As the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-use-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#stored-procedures) says, when you execute a stored procedure, you need to provide partition key value. But you provide your partition key path("/ActivityId"), not your partition key value. This is why you get 0 count. So you need to pass `"1816820"` as partition key value to execute your stored procedure. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Awesome !! Thanks much @Steve. You're awesome :)